# How to expose ActiveSupport instrumentation metrics as HTTP response headers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

```
(78.3ms) ItemsController -- Completed #active -- { :view_runtime => 10.46, :db_runtime => 6.76, :controller => "ItemsController", :action => "active", :format => "*/*", :method => "GET", :path => "/active", :status => 200, :status_message => "OK" }
```

I'm wondering if there is any simple method of exposing these ActiveSupport Instrumentation metrics(`view_runtime`, `db_runtime`) as HTTP response headers.

My use case is the following:

staging/beta environment that's a bit annoying to get into(VPN + ssh + cat/grep/tail) + it is used pretty heavily so it's not very easy to spot the messages I'm looking for.
But if it was accessible in Web inspector for AJAX requests, then it is better visibility.

Just to be clear, I'm aware of New Relic but this would be an overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: Probably you mean ActiveRecord, not ActiveSupport

Comment: The [meta_request gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/meta_request/versions/0.7.3) together with the RailsPanel Chrome extension does pretty much exactly this. Unfortunately it hasn't been updated for Rails 7 yet. But its source code should contain most of answers you want.

Comment: @max would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure how much of an answer it is really considering that it doesn't work for Rails 7.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `view_runtime` might be harder to get in a controller but `db_runtime` seems to be pretty straightforward if there aren't any queries triggered from templates.

```ruby
db_runtime = ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber.runtime
response.headers['db_runtime'] = ("ActiveRecord: %.1fms" % db_runtime.to_f) if db_runtime
```